# R how to match a data with dot inside and also set boundaries

Tags: r, string, match

I am using grepl and str_detect to match with data but the some variables have a dot inside, some not, I don't know which has which not. also we need to set a boundary $ at the end. 
e.g.

```
query<-c("3.2","345","1.5","23")
data<-c("342","3.2","34","1.5","165","234","345")
```

so, if `data[which(grepl(x=data,pattern="3.2",value=TRUE)]`
we can get 3.2, but if pattern is 23, we will get both 23 and 234
so I use `data[which(grepl(x=data,pattern="23$")]`
we can get 23 without 234, but if pattern is 3.2, we will get 3.2 and 342.
how to meet these two standard at the same time?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using `grepl` here since you don't seem to want to use regular expressions (dots are special characters in regular expressions). Just something like `data[data=="3.2"]` would pull out just the value you need. Also are you using `str_detect` in you actual code because that's not in the example you have.

Comment: I also tried str_detect, but the same problem, cannot meet two requirements at the same time

Comment: So what exactly is the desired result here? Are there cases when you trying not to do an exact match?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\\.` to specify the `.` in your code. If you're looking for any string that ends in `3.2`, the below code would work:

```
vec <- c('342','3.2','34','1.5','165','234','345', '3.22', '193.2', '232')

> grep(pattern = '.*3\\.2$', x = vec, ignore.case = T, value = T)
[1] "3.2"   "193.2"
```

you can read more on the expressions at: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/regular-expressions.html